# Migraciones en Laravel crea bigIncrements() y no BigSerial

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postgresql, migration

Estoy utilizando Migrations para crear las tablas de mi base de datos, pero cuando utilizo el tipo de dato bigIncrements en vez de crearme un campo de tipo Big Serial me crea uno de tipo Big Integer.

¿Qué tipo de metodo debo utilizar para que en Migrations mi campo se cree de tipo Big Serial y no de tipo Big Integer?

Utilizo como motor de base de datos PostgreSQL

A continuación el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando en la base de datos el campo es de tipo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

**Sección 1**

Si revisas la documentación de Laravel en el apartado de las [migraciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#generating-migrations) notarás como un campo declarado asi:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Es un equivalente de:

> **`Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key)`** equivalent column.

Dado lo cual utilizar la instrucción anterior siempre creará un tipo de dato `BIGINT` y no `BIGSERIAL`.

**Sección 2**

Ahora bien analizando la documentación de [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html), tenemos que:

Un dato de tipo `BIGINT` posee las siguientes características:

```
bigint  8 bytes large-range integer -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
```

Mientras que un `BIGSERIAL`

```
bigserial   8 bytes large autoincrementing integer  1 to 9223372036854775807
```

Donde como puedes notar:

- Su tamaño de almacenamiento es el mismo
- `BIGINT` es superior en rango de almacenamiento en valores negativos o con signo
- `BIGINT` no es autoincrement, sin embargo eso en las bases de datos se aplica indicando que sea `AUTO_INCREMENT`

**Sección 3**

Ahora si regresas al primer enlace que te he provisto notarás como dentro de los métodos que tiene Laravel para múltiples tipos de datos no se encuentra un `BIGSERIAL` o algún equivalente que lo genere, dado lo cual me parece tendrás que:

- Decantarte por `bigincrements` el cual de todos modos va a generar una columna con las siguientes características:

  - Con el atributo `PK` o llave primaria
  - Que sea entero grande sin signo
  - Que los valores que se ingresan sean autoincrementables

Finalmente aclarando respecto a las 2 líneas que tienes comentadas en tu imagen, el tipo de dato `BIGINT` no es solo para PostgreSQL sino para todo aquel gestor de bases de datos que soporte dicho tipo.

Comment: Tal cual, en un proyecto que estuve usaban postgreSql y bigincrements sin ningún problema.

Comment: Todo depende de la estructura de la base de datos que desees, se colocan de tipo serials cuando quieres restringir que si o si ese campo sea autoincremental y que sin importar el día de mañana que sistema le pegues a la base de datos tu estructura y tu integridad de datos este protegida.

Comment: Cuando mencionas que sea auto incremental no veo relación, pues como ya te mencioné con usar `bigIncrements` esto genera un campo PK y AUTO_INCREMENT, lo que mencionas solo son características de cada gestor